# User object to populate md-items in md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I want to populate my md-autocomplete with an object containing user objects. It's retrieved in JSON format through a factory into `$scope.users`. I can check the object in my console using an Angular viewer.

```
users:
    user_id:
        display_name: "value"
        first_name: "value"
        last_name: "value"
    user_id:
        display_name: "value"
        first_name: "value"
        last_name: "value"
    etc...
```

I want the model value to be set to the `user_id` model and the display text to be `display_name`. Is this possible? I have tried (according to the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) only the `md-items` attribute should be required

```
<md-autocomplete md-items="u in users"></autocomplete>
```

But it doesn't do anything. Neither does following the "basic example"

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="videoInfo.lineUp.1" md-search-text="looseheadSearchText" md-items="u in users" md-item-text="u.display_name"></md-autocomplete>
```

### EDIT

Here's the code I use to get my `users` object:

```
angular.module("app").controller("MainController", ["$scope", "userRepository", function ($scope, userRepository) {
    userRepository.get(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    });

app.factory("userRepository",
    function($resource) {
        return $resource("/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite-child/inc/get_users.php");
    });
```

Comment: Check this link out, read their docs on md-autocomplete, https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete and try them out before asking.

Comment: I did, but I used this link: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete. I though only the md-items attribute was required to make this work. I saw that there is also a md-item-text attribute, but that's not the issue at hand. I can't get the items to load, and the documentation is just not clear enough for me to understand...

Comment: @SLearner Do you have any tips on how to implement the `searchQuery` function described in all the documentation examples? I really don't get the documentation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<md-autocomplete
    md-selected-item="videoInfo.lineUp[1]"
    md-search-text="searchText"
    md-items="item in searchQuery(searchText)"
    md-item-text="item.display">
</md-autocomplete>
```

Angular `searchQuery()` function:

```
$scope.searchQuery = function (searchText) {
    var query = searchText.toLowerCase();
    var users = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.users,
        function (value, key) {
            // value = user object
            // key = userId
            var dN = value["display_name"];
            if (dN) {
                var obj = {};
                obj[key] = value;
                obj["display"] = dN;
                if (dN.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) !== -1) {
                    users.push(obj);
                }
            }
        });
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always take a look at the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) first before asking a question.

It says you need at least something like this:

```
<md-autocomplete
      md-selected-item="selectedUser"
      md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)"
      md-search-text="searchText"
      md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)"
      md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
      md-item-text="item.display_name"
      md-min-length="0"
      placeholder="What is your favorite User?">
    <md-item-template>
      <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display_name}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
      No states matching "{{searchText}}" were found.
    </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

Hope it helps

**UPDATE**

`searchQuery()` is a function that gets called every time you type something. Basically, what you need is a function that returns all users if nothing is written or only the users whose names include whatever is written in the autocomplete input.

You should not do exactly what is done in examples. Because you are using real `$http` requests and they do not. They just simulate it with the help of different functions like timeout and map. Your function should look something like this:

```
$scope.searchQuery = function(searchText){
     return userRepository.get(searchText);
}
```

That's it.

As for using `this` instead of `$scope`, this is what [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) recommends in his angular styleguide. He says `$scope` should be used in more specific conditions only.

Comment: Actually I did look at the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) first, but it struck me that only the `md-items` attribute was required (why else is there a * in front of it right?)

Comment: Maybe I should have stated it more clearly, so I revised my question. I suspect it has something to do with the `querySearch()` function from the documentation. However, I don't get how it works.

Comment: @SjorsHijgenaar how do you get your `users` data? are you getting it through `$http` request?

Comment: @Jaohngir Rahmonov Yes, I will edit the code to incorporate it.

Comment: @SjorsHijgenaar see my update for an explanation of what `searchQuery()` is

Comment: What does the map function do? Because if I simply return `$scope.users` from the function, still nothing happens

Comment: And why do the documentation examples employ a `var self = this` construction? I guess that's also why they use `ctrl.searchText()` rather than `searchText`. Does md-autocomplete create a separate `$scope`?

Comment: @SjorsHijgenaar answered your questions in the update.

Comment: I can see the function being called, but it simply returns all user objects... There's no filtering going on and there's no dropdown of options either. Nothing happens really